# Can you use an <aside> element inside a <section role="main"> element?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm in the process of improving accessibility in my HTML using HTML5 and WAI-ARIA.

It is OK to have the following set up?

```
<!-- main content -->
<section id="main" role="main">
    <h1>The main content</h1>

    <!-- This div needs to be here for styling reasons -->
    <div class="the-content">    
         <p>All the text that goes with the main content</p>
    </div>

    <!-- the sidebar -->
    <aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
        <h2>A title</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    <aside>
</section>
```

The thing I'm not sure of is if I should have the `<aside>` element outside of the `<section>` and the `role="main"` container. Does that matter?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. It implies you are asking about putting an `<aside>` element inside a `<main>` element, while the code you have is an `<aside>` inside a parent `<section>`

Comment: I've updated the title, thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does matter yes.  Where to put it is defined by how the content in the `aside` tag relates to the main `section`.

For example:

If the content in the `aside` is related to the main article, it should be inside the `main section`.  However if the content inside the `sidebar aside tag` is different to `main` I would put it outside of the `main section`

http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it the `<aside>` inside the `<section>` is perfectly valid markup and will pass W3C validation, if that's what you're worried about.

The `<section>` element [**allows flow content inside**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-section-element) which may include the `<aside>` element - however if you're only using sections for styling purposes, you should probably be using a div instead.

Aside from that (pun intended) I have my doubts on the `role=main` part being valid - [**according to this**](http://rawgithub.com/w3c/aria-in-html/master/index.html), the only role attribute values allowed on `<section>` elements are shown below:

> **Default ARIA semantics:**
>
> `role=region`.
>
> **What Other ARIA roles, states and properties may be used?**
>
> `alert`, `alertdialog`, `application`, `contentinfo`, `dialog`, `document`, `log`,
>   `marquee`, `search`, or `status`.
>
> Any global `aria-*` attributes and any aria-* attributes applicable to
>   the allowed roles.

Which rather notably doesn't include the `main` role.

Answer (score 3):

The spec ([editor's draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) that already includes `main`) doesn't allow to nest the `main` element inside `article`, `aside`, `footer`, `header` or `nav`, but it doesn't say anything about nesting these elements inside `main`. It also provides two examples that use `article` and `nav` (intra-document navigation) inside `main`. So at least `aside`, nested in the `article` or `section` (and therefore scoped to its level), should be also allowed. I also can imagine the case where some part of content with some supplementary info inside (like in the [`aside` usage examples](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_aside_element#Example_1%3a_the_.3Caside.3E_Element) in the WCAG Wiki) may form together the main content of the page, so I don't think that disallowing it would be reasonable.

On the other hand, the outline algorithm (which now seems to be the primary reason for the existence of all [sectioning content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content), including `aside`) is still marked [as being 'at risk'](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/#status-of-this-document), so the definition of these elements may change and some clarification may be added.

Probably we should ask this question to the HTML5 spec editors?

Answer (score 2):

I will concur with Darren in regards to where you drop the tag. Also, your tagging is a little wacky. Various tags have WAI-ARIA roles natively, while yes you can overwrite native roles, but why would you? This [post about WAI-ARIA](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/02/using-wai-aria-landmarks-2013/) on the Paciello Group's blog talks about it more. Ex:

Insstead of using

```
<section id="main" role="main">
```

you could just use `<main>`, which means the same thing, and better practice. The `<aside>` tag has the complementary role added natively, so that is  like saying My name is Ryan, really my name *is Ryan*.

Comment: I heard somewhere that it's sensible to add roles to HTML5 elements for maximum compatibility, is this true?

Comment: The only one I have heard this argument for is `<nav>`. I'd need to review those sources before commenting further.

Comment: Conincidentally I was just reading an article about the <main> element by Bruce Lawson, and he mentions he still explicitly adds roles to elements such as nav and main: http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2014/should-you-use-html5-header-and-footer/#comment-1869844

Comment: Actually <section role="main"> isn't the same as <main> since the sencond is not a sectioning element, which is a really useful property if you are concerned about document outline (and you should)!